# Apply a function to a List of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, list-manipulation

I need help in how to manage lists in an iterative way.

I have the following list `list` which is composed of several dataframes with same columns, but different number of rows. Example:

```
[[1]]
  id InpatientDays ERVisits OfficeVisits Narcotics
1  a             0        0           18         1
2  b             1        1            6         1
3  c             0        0            5         3
4  d             0        1           19         0
5  e             8        2           19         3
6  f             2        0            9         2

[[2]]
    id InpatientDays ERVisits OfficeVisits Narcotics
7   a            16        1            8         1
8   b             2        0            8         0
9   c             2        1            4         3
10  d             4        2            0         2
11  e             6        5           20         2
12  a             0        0            7         4
```

I would like to apply a function to get all the possible combinations for the id for each "data frame" in the list.

I intended to try something like this `lapply(list1, function(x) combn(unique(list1[x]$id)))` Which of course does not work.. expecting to get something like:

```
[[1]]  
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"   "c"   "c"   "d"   "d"   "e"  
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "f"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "f"  "d"   "e"   "f"   "e"   "f"   "f"  

[[2]] 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "c"  "d"  
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "d"  "e"  "e"
```

Is this possible? I know for sure this works for a single dataframe `df`

```
  combn(unique(df$id),2)
```

Comment: I wonder if you have noticed some pattern in retagging of your [recent](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36066336/revisions) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36048558/revisions)... Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dataframes/info) is somewhat helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to use `unique(x$id)`

```
 lapply(list1, function(x) combn(unique(x$id),2))
```

---

The OP's code is looping the 'list1' using `lapply`.  The anonymous function call (`function(x)`) returns each of the 'data.frame' within the `list` i.e. 'x' is the 'data.frame'.  So, we just need to call `x$id` (or `x[['id']]`) to extract the 'id' column.  In essence, 'x' is not an index.  But, if we need to subset based on the index, we have to loop through the sequence of 'list1' (or if the `list` elements are named, then loop through the `names` of it)

```
lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i) combn(unique(list1[[i]]$id), 2))
```