# How to deal with huge dataframes and lists in R

Tags: r, list, combinations, large-data-volumes

I recently asked a question on how to apply a function on data frames inside a list. Hereby I show the link, where it worked perfectly executing the answer received in the post.

[Apply a function to a List of dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066336/apply-a-function-to-a-list-of-dataframes-in-r/36066393#36066393)

Where in this example it was only two dataframes of size `6x6` in the list.

As I tried to replicate the output for my list, I get the following error.

```
Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
 invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
 In addition: Warning message:
 In combn(unique(x$id), 2) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

My List is basically a big data frame `2328439 signatures of 11 variables` divided in chunks making a list of `Large list 6236 elements, 3.5Gb`

I basically want to pair up all the possible combinations of them and compare them side by side, but since it is huge, I decided to try and group them, so the data is divided in chunks, which are different data frames to be paired.

If we consider the `signatures` data frame, before dividing it in chunks, it would be like this:

```
> ids <- combn(unique(signatures$uniqueid),2)
Error in combn(unique(signatures$uniqueid), 2) : n < m
```

So this code works for a small dataset,( Reference: [R Generate non repeating pairs in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048558/r-generate-non-repeating-pairs-in-dataframe))  but as I tried it on my big data frame I got the previous error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How many unique values are there for `uniqueid`?

Comment: There are `2328439 unique_id`, which means that there are these amount of signatures. When splitting it into blocks, I get 6236 different data frames, with different amount of `unique_id`

Comment: That's a lot of pairwise comparisons. Makes me wonder why this is even needed?

Comment: As a project for my Masters program, we are trying an author disambiguation.. So I guess is the method I have thought to compare authors distances.. But I mean, I might be wrong, I am just trying to look if this method could work.